# Drawing overlapping implications

Tags: diagrams, arrows

I need to draw the following diagram wherein I use $\Rightarrow$ in vertical and horizontal way. Observe that, the word "independent"  should be written on the diagonal line which connecting State.1 and State.4

[image]

Comment: I found the following: $$\begin{CD}
 1 @>implies>> 2\\
 @VVimpliesV @VVimpliesV\\
  4 @>implies>>  3
\end{CD}$$ but I coudnt add diagonal line and write on it

Comment: You might try:  https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd?lang=en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm no expert at `tikz-cd`, but it has plenty of good examples in [the manual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd?lang=en).  Here's my effort:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{mathtools}% for \text{}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=2cm, column sep=3cm]
    \text{State 1} \arrow[d] \arrow[rd, dash, "\text{independent}" description] 
    &
    \text{State 3} \arrow[l] \arrow[d] 
    \\
    \text{State 2}           
    & 
    \text{State 4} \arrow[l]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Notes:

- I've used `\text{...}` to format the labels, because `tikz-cd` assumes that there's a math formula at each point.  Without the `\text{}` they come out as words in math italic, which looks terrible.
- for the diagonal arrow: `rd` makes it go right and down from `State 1`; `dash` makes it into a line with no arrow head; and `description` after the label puts the label neatly in the middle.
- I've also added plenty of space using the optional `row sep` and `column sep` arguments, so that there is room for the label on the diagonal
- I do not know of an easy way to rotate the text of the label in `tikz-cd`. You could load the `graphicx` package, and use `"\rotatebox{-30}{\text{independent}}"` but you would have to guess the angle and correct it by hand.

I'm not sure that `tikz-cd` is really the best tool for this type of diagram.  It might be better just drawn in plain `tikz` or with Metapost.

Comment: Thanks dear, it is not working with the following packages which necessary in my article:
\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath,amscd}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphics}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{mathtools}

Comment: It works fine at my end, even with all those packages added.  I'm afraid I'm not a remote debugging service!

Comment: No, you are not. But it did not work with me and I wrote the comment so that someone else can give a help. Thanks for your effort.